# Claims wording: too narrow and subject to workaround?

Tags: claims

A test and measurement system records data.   Would it be better to indicate:

A test and measurement system that forwards data to a data store .  (not a 'database').

OR is it 'good enough' to state:

> A test and measurement system that saves data in a networked database.

I am concerned that the latter is too specific and a competitor could implement \ design  a 'work-around' a narrow claim.  I think that it is best to use broad terms in the claims and use more specific language to describe the system elsewhere (enablement).  If this is incorrect or nuanced, I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a preamble to a claim. A claim would be 
"A test and measurement system that saves data in a networked database comprising:
[then list the components and specifically how they fit together].

Or, if it is a method claim -
"A test and measurement system that saves data in a networked database comprising the steps of
[doing this, doing that, doing something else]

Answer (score 0):

When reading that I have four question:

> What's the difference between test and measurement?
>
> Do you need to do both always?
>
> Whats's a networked database?
>
> Why can't it save data elsewhere?

If you have perfect answers to all of those, you might be fine. If not, think again.

A claim is not about wording - okay, sure it is, but - it's about the **content** of the words. It doesn't matter if you describe your system with this word or that word or those words, what matters is having the facts straight.

Which are **the completly necessary elements to distinguish your invention from the prior art**, how are they defined (specifics go into the description, but it should be understandable from the claims)  and how do they work together?